# Continue Button on 'Billing Information' on checkout page not work in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am using magento 1.9. All work fine on desktop but when i place order through mobile and as non-login user then Continue button not work and not move to next step. In work is shows session expired in save billing address please help if any one know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you have problem with below controller action

```
checkout/onepage/saveBilling/
```

(Here checkout is the module name, onepage is the controller name and saveBilling is the action name)

Things you can do to debug:

1. Enable logs and open system.log and exception.log
2. Clear log files.
3. Hit the Save Billing button.
4. See If you got some errors in above two log files.
5. Vote up and accept the answer if helps :).